# Мягкий знак в справочнике Розенталя

Tags: мягкий-знак

В справочнике Розенталя есть три параграфа про мягкий знак: один — про мягкий знак в глаголах, другой — про мягкий знак в наречиях, а третий про что? Это мягкий знак в существительных или вообще во всех словах? [Вот этот параграф, или раздел, или что это вообще такое и кто так организовывает?](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=31#pp31)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще во всех словах. Почему? Там не ограничено какой-то частью речи. От некоторых таких слов можно и наречие образовать: *объективно, серьёзно, вьюжно [на улице]*. Речь о том, когда твёрдый знак пишется вместо мягкого. Связано это с тем, что ситуации похожи (например, можно произнести твёрдо — "шампинйон", "вйюга", а нужен мягкий знак).

> кто так организовывает?

Хороший вопрос. Это не оригинальный справочник, его кто-то переделал. У оригинальных справочников Розенталя есть год выпуска, здесь же он не указан.

Comment: Мне кажется, что надо править, *oleedd*, ведь речь в вопросе идет о **мягком знаке**. Вы же приводите пример с твердым: объективно. И пишете: *Речь о том, когда твёрдый знак пишется вместо мягкого.* Разве?

Comment: Наречия образованы от слов из данного раздела (а там твёрдый тоже), и вопрос о нём, а не о мягком знаке. Хотел там добавить "или наоборот", но потом решил так и оставить, а то немного смешно звучит. Не выбрал "мягкий вместо твёрдого", потому что твёрдый редко и логичнее "редкое вместо частого", чем "частое вместо редкого". Это фраза образная: не конкретно речь о том, а суть такова.